# Microsoft.PlayerFramework failed to stream .mjpg file

Tags: windows-store-apps

xmlns:VideoStream="using:Microsoft.PlayerFramework"

VideoStream:MediaPlayer Source="http://155.41.145.37/mjpg/video.mjpg"

Worked fine when i change the Source pointed to .mp4 file. When changing to .mjpg it won't work. When running it shows the error " This video is failed to play".

Please help

Vishnu Aravind

Comment: Is that a live-feed from an IP-camera? please secure it.. sooner rather than later

Comment: Yes its a live feed from an IP camera

Answer (score 0):

This works:

Doc: https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder

Download:
http://mjpeg.codeplex.com/

Sample code:

```
MjpegDecoder _mjpeg;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    _mjpeg = new MjpegDecoder();
    _mjpeg.FrameReady += mjpeg_FrameReady;

    _mjpeg.ParseStream(new Uri("http://155.41.145.37/mjpg/video.mjpg"));
}

private async void mjpeg_FrameReady(object sender, FrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    // Convert IBuffer to IRandomAccessStream.
    var ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await ras.WriteAsync(e.FrameBuffer);
    ras.Seek(0);

    // Show image.
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(ras);
    image.Source = bitmap;
}
```